# Getting the file type of a zip file in input file

Tags: javascript, jquery, mime-types, input-type-file

I am trying to catch a file on a `input[type=file]` change event :

Here is my HTML :

```
<input type="file" id="file-upload" name="file-upload">
```

Here is my JavaScript (using jQuery) :

```
$('#file-upload').bind("change", function(e){
    var file = (e.srcElement || e.target).files[0];
    console.log(e);
}
```

It works fully fine with images, txt, doc, docx, xlsx etc etc etc BUT NOT with zip files.
When I try it with a zip file, the var file contains a type attributes empty.

Do you have an idea why and how i could get it?

**EDIT 1**
I use Chrome Browser, in Windows 7. My files are zipped with 7zip.

**EDIT 2**
here is what I get :

[image: Console log]

Comment: What do you mean by "*var file contains a type attributes empty*" What attributes? Where do you use `file` in your script? What does it output?

Comment: It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/rvd6T/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works.

I tried enapupe's fiddle and it works
http://jsfiddle.net/rvd6T/

```
$('#file-upload').bind("change", function(e){
var file = (e.srcElement || e.target).files[0];
console.log(file);
console.log(e);
});
```

My console log
[image]

---

You should be be aware that the types will vary.

sometimes it would be **type: "application/x-zip-compressed"** or **"application/zip"**

You most likely should just base it on the **filename** instead,
*.zip (ends with zip & case insensitive)

but still must check it on server side if its actually a ZIP file and unzipable

Comment: It's not working on my side, even with your jsfiddle :( I edited my question with some more precisions.

Comment: Like I said, base it on the filename instead. but have another server-side checking later on

Comment: I will use this solution. Just wondering why it's not working.

Comment: Some versions of Chrome (e.g. Google Chrome) are quite strict and have this security features. Just don't rely on the "type" field, since other browsers as well are probably going to follow this later on

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation, but the thing is I am making a dataUrlParsing so if i go with the fileName, how will i differentiate "application/x-zip-compressed" and "application/zip" for example ? Is there a side effect if i always put "application/zip" ?